# How do I override a toString() method in Java?

Tags: java, overriding, tostring

Ok, so on my assignment that I am working on, I have a file that has the instructions commented, and below that is the code I wrote. I think I am good on everything EXCEPT overriding the ToString method. I think I'm starting the line good, I just cant figure out how to get the output going.

These are the instructions:

```
// Instruction 4
//TODO: Override the toString() method to return the account number,
//      account name, and account balance. The returned string should look
//      like:
//      Account: 10001 - General Expenses
//      Balance: 450.67
```

This is what I have so far:

```
public String toString(){
  return "Accounts: " + accountNumber + " " + accountName + " " + accountBalance;
```

Here is the whole file called Account.java:

```
// TODO: Add your name as a comment at the top of the code.
// Gary Hicks - CIT2551

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package finalexam;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

/**
 *
 * @author duvalls
 */
public class Account {
    private String accountNumber, accountName;
    private BigDecimal accountBalance;

    public Account(){
        accountNumber = "";
        accountName = "";
        accountBalance = new BigDecimal("0");
    }

    // Instruction 2 - create an overloaded constructor
    // TODO: Create an overloaded constructor that accepts parameters for 
    //       AccountNumber, AccountName, and AccountBalance. Assign the parameter
    //       values to the corresponding private variables.
    public Account(String accountNumber, String accountName, BigDecimal accountBalance)
    {
      this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
      this.accountName = accountName;
      this.accountBalance = accountBalance;
    }


    // Instruction 3 - create get and set methods for the properties.
    //************************************************************************   
    // TODO: Create getAccountNumber method to return the value of the private
    //       accountNumber variable.
    public String getAccountNumber(){
      return accountNumber;
    }

    //TODO: Create a setAccountNumber method that does not return a value and 
    //      accepts a String parameter. Assign the parameter's value to the 
    //      private accountNumber variable. 
    public void setAccountNumber ( String n ){
      accountNumber = n;
    }

    //************************************************************************    
    // TODO: Create getAccountName method to return the value of the private
    //       accountName variable.
    public String getAccountName(){
      return accountName;
    }

    //TODO: Create a setAccountName method that does not return a value and 
    //      accepts a String parameter. Assign the parameter's value to the 
    //      private accountName variable.    
    public void setAccountName ( String n ){
      accountName = n;
    }

    //************************************************************************

    // TODO: Create getAccountBalance method to return the value of the private
    //       accountBalance variable.
    public BigDecimal getAccountBalance(){
      return accountBalance;
    }    

    //TODO: Create a setAccountBalance method that does not return a value and 
    //      accepts a BigDecimal parameter. Assign the parameter's value to the 
    //      private accountBalance variable. 
    public void setAccountBalance ( BigDecimal n ){
      accountBalance = n;
    }

    // Instruction 4
    //TODO: Override the toString() method to return the account number,
    //      account name, and account balance. The returned string should look
    //      like:
    //      Account: 10001 - General Expenses
    //      Balance: 450.67
    public String toString(){
      return "Accounts: " + accountNumber + " " + accountName + " " + accountBalance;

    } 
}
```

This is the other file called AccountJFrame.java:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package finalexam;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.ArrayList;
/**
 *
 * @author duvalls
 */
public class AccountJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    ArrayList <Account> myAccounts = new ArrayList();
    /**
     * Creates new form AccountJFrame
     */
    public AccountJFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">//GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
    private void initComponents()
    {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        createAccountButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        listAccountsButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        exitButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        accountNumberTextField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        accountNameTextField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        accountBalanceTextField = new javax.swing.JTextField();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Final Exam");

        jLabel1.setText("Account No:");

        jLabel2.setText("Account name:");

        jLabel3.setText("Account balance:");

        createAccountButton.setText("Create Account");
        createAccountButton.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter()
        {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt)
            {
                createAccountButtonMouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });

        listAccountsButton.setText("List Accounts");
        listAccountsButton.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter()
        {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt)
            {
                listAccountsButtonMouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });

        exitButton.setText("Exit");
        exitButton.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter()
        {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt)
            {
                exitButtonMouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(accountNumberTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 127, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(accountBalanceTextField)
                    .addComponent(accountNameTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(14, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(accountNumberTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(accountNameTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(accountBalanceTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(30, 30, 30))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(27, 27, 27)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(createAccountButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(exitButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(listAccountsButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(20, 20, 20)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(createAccountButton))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addComponent(listAccountsButton))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                    .addComponent(exitButton))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>//GEN-END:initComponents

    private void createAccountButtonMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_createAccountButtonMouseClicked

        // Instruction 5
        // TODO: Create a BigDecimal variable named balance and
        //       assign the account balance entered in the TextField to it.


        //Instruction 6
        //TODO: Create an instance of the Account class named myAccount by calling the overloaded
        //      constructor and passing the entry made in the Account Number
        //      and Account Name TextFields and the balance BigDecimal variable.

        //Instruction 7
        //TODO: Use JOptionPane to show a message that contains the results 
        //      of calling the myAccount.toString() method.

        // Instruction 8
        //TODO: Add myAccount to the myAccounts ArrayList

        // Instruction 9
        //TODO: Clear the TextField controls

    }//GEN-LAST:event_createAccountButtonMouseClicked

    private void listAccountsButtonMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_listAccountsButtonMouseClicked

        String allAccounts = "";

        //Instruction 10
        //TODO: Loop through the myAccounts ArrayList. Inside of the loop, add  the result returned 
        //      from calling the toString() method for each Account object in the ArrayList
        //      to the allAccounts String variable. 

             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, allAccounts, "Account List",
             JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }//GEN-LAST:event_listAccountsButtonMouseClicked

    private void exitButtonMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_exitButtonMouseClicked
        // TODO: Add code to close the application
        System.exit(0);
    }//GEN-LAST:event_exitButtonMouseClicked

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AccountJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AccountJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AccountJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AccountJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new AccountJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify//GEN-BEGIN:variables
    private javax.swing.JTextField accountBalanceTextField;
    private javax.swing.JTextField accountNameTextField;
    private javax.swing.JTextField accountNumberTextField;
    private javax.swing.JButton createAccountButton;
    private javax.swing.JButton exitButton;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JButton listAccountsButton;
    // End of variables declaration//GEN-END:variables
}
```

Comment: Sorry, on my actual file it has the instructions commented out right above my code.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen exactly? What exactly do you mean by "get the output going"? Output what to where? I see no attempt to "output" anything.

Comment: So, you are asking us to help you with your final exam?  Does your school have an honor system?  Do you want your question out here where someone else could see it and report you?

Comment: No, the final exam was different, but related. Instead of trying to hurt someone, you could ask questions first. My final exam was different but somewhat similar and I just needed help on 1 thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit after long comment thread figuring out the problem: You need to make a new Account instance, set the values and then in some way call a toString on it with the output going to somewhere you can see. As mentioned in the newly added instructions 6 and 7.

And this is not your actual problem, but you should use the @Override annotation on the method you’re overriding. That said, your IDE should probably tell you this.

```
@Override
public String toString(){
  return "Accounts: " + accountNumber + " " + accountName + " " + accountBalance;
```

I’ll leave editing the actual String so it adheres to the assignment to you.

Comment: Sorry, on the actual file the instructions are commented right above my code. So I'm starting off on the right track correct?

Comment: @user2441911 yes... but why not just run it and try?

Comment: I edited my original post to include the entire file

Comment: I have ran it and I do not get any errors, but it doesn't seem like it is storing the information, and it is not displaying it.

Comment: @user2441911 There is no main method so what exactly did you run? Just compiling the code doesn’t instantiate this class or call the toString method.

Comment: So I don't get it, what am I doing wrong? It looks like I've completed all of the instructions.

Comment: I swear I'm not looking for answers, I've made it this far myself. Just need a nudge in the right direction as to what I need to do next.

Comment: I guess the instructions assumed that you already know how to create and run a Java program. Maybe you should backtrack in your material about how to do that, or find a basic Java tutorial online. Right now what information would you even expect to be shown? You don’t have any place where you actually instantiate this class with values.

Comment: The program is already created. This is just the code to make it function. What I posted is my Account.java file, should I also include the AccountJFrame.java and AccountJFrame.form files as well?

Comment: Just show us the place where you make a new Account instance, set the values and then in some way call a toString on it with the output going to somewhere you can see.

Comment: I edited my post and pasted the code from the other file included.

Comment: You haven’t read your instructions starting from instruction 5 yet.

Comment: Basically everything I told you is in instruction 6 and 7.